# Is It Possible to Do a Realtime Analysis of Polyphonic Audio in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, audio

I recently read this [thesis](http://digitalcommons.calpoly.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1853&context=theses) on audio analysis of guitar chords, and I was curious if this could be accomplished in Javascript. Are there libraries which support the analysis of polyphonic audio, using the web audio API, which can allow me to detect multiple notes simultaneously within the browser (using NodeJS or Flask I would be open to doing this on the server)? This could possibly be achieved by using the [NMF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_matrix_factorization) algorithm combined with [STFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform), but I'm not entirely sure how to go about it.

Comment: Ultimately, the answer is likely "yes", but as written, the question isn't really OT for SO. If you have a specific problem, with a specific library, for example, that'd be the time to revisit. Browser vs. non-browser JS also matters, potentially a lot.

Comment: @DaveNewton I've now added to the question that this is within the browser. If the answer is yes, would you be able to be able to point me towards libraries that support this functionality?

Comment: yes it is possible. good luck.

Comment: @whitebox How would you suggest I go about doing this?

Comment: If you read the thesis then please give us an Executive Summary in pseudo code of its algorithm(s) and we'll better help you.  Today javascript is on par with c/c++/java on speed if typed arrays can be used, so short answer is yes.  People are using GPGPU from javascript if you need screaming speed